# How to retrieve a specific group of children from firebase realtime database

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created a social media app. Suppose I have one array list which contains all the uids of users I follow on my app, stored in child of (following), I also created a child of (posts) which has all posts, posted by all users. The problem is I don't want to use snapshot.getChildern() to retrieve posts which equals following because it downloads whole data under 'posts' child. Is there any way I can retrieve only those posts which matches with 'following' array list?(for Posts Database looks like this)-->
Clicks  /  UID  {`title : "sky"` `imageurl : "https...."`  `publisher : "UID"` `timestamp : "1666456456.."`}

and second one --> follow / UID / following / other user's uid : true

functions I use :

```
  private void checkFollowing(){
    followingList = new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseReference reference = Util.getDatabase().getReference("follow")
            .child(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid())
            .child("following");


    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            followingList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                followingList.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            }

            readClicksPosts();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}

private void readClicksPosts() {
    DatabaseReference reference = Util.getDatabase().getReference("Clicks");
    reference.orderByChild("timestamp").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            clicks_models_List.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot datasnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Clicks_Model clicks_model = datasnapshot.getValue(Clicks_Model.class);
                for (String id : followingList) {
                    assert clicks_model != null;
                    if (clicks_model.getPublisher().equals(id)) {
                        clicks_models_List.add(clicks_model);
                    }
                }
            }
            Collections.reverse(clicks_models_List);
            clicksAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            DatabaseReference.goOffline();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

I just want to show posts from people I follow, what should I do if I don't to use .getChildren() method. Please keep in mind the posts are going to update frequently.

Comment: Instead of describing what your database looks like, please edit your question and add a screenshot of it. Please also indicate the exact query you want to perform.

Comment: You're going to want to [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) to order/filter the data, but as Alex said: it's hard to say more without seeing the data that you're querying and the way you current filter it.

Comment: please check i updated question and screenshot service is down unfortunately.